# Froala setting the placeholder text after initialization

Tags: jquery, froala

The Froala editor component has many settings available at initialisation, including the placeholder.

However, I have a case where I must change the placeholder after initialisation.

I cannot see in the [API docs](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/methods) any method to do this. I tried looking for a method on the Froala object via console.logging() it, but there is some obscurification that makes this unclear.

I tried:

```
$("<selector>").froalaEditor.placeholder("new value...");
```

and

```
$("<selector>").froalaEditor.({placeholder : "new value..."});
```

I am not posting a working snippet because this is not a coding issue specifically, but I can do if anyone believes it would be substantially useful.

Time is pressing so I would accept a jquery solution outside the manufacturers API for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering my own question based a response from Froala support, both for future readers and as a reminder for myself.

From a case in Jan 2017 [here](https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/issues/1678#issuecomment-270628939) then answer given is:

To set an option after the editor was initialized, you would have to do it like this:

```
$('.selector').data('froala.editor').opts.placeholderText = 'foobar';
$('.selector').froalaEditor('placeholder.refresh');
```

I enquired if there was a documentation page showing this technique but was advised that the recommended method is to actually erase and re-create the Froala editor instance with the required placeholder parameter. Additionally there was mention of some potential documentation showing this technique for specific cases like placeholder, which I take to mean that not all 'opts' members can be altered this way.